# iPhone ignores media queries

Tags: ios, css, iphone, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a problem with my media queries. I finished my responsive website and everything was ok on desktop, Android and Windows Phone devices. I asked my friends to check if it's ok on their iPhones and I got supriesed, because their iPhones (with iOS 10) are ignoring my media queries.

How it's possible? Problem is only on iPhones (5,5s,6,6s+). When I scale website in Chrome, everything is fine.

I have meta viewport tag in my head section.

This is my media query:

```
@media (min-device-width: 220px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
{
  /*my styling*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@necilAlbayrak is right. Here you have correct media queries for iphones

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thank you, I've tried, but unfortunetaly nothing happend.

Answer (score 2):

try : (added `screen`)

```
@media screen (min-device-width: 220px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
{
  /*my styling*/
}
```

**PLUS,** add this to your HTML in every responsive page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Unfortunetaly, when I add "screen", my media queries which worked before doesn't work now. I have this tag.

Comment: Did you try `@media screen and (...)...`? I think the `and` after the `screen` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

can you try using min-width and max-width instead of device width. sometimes device-width does not match viewport.

```
@media screen (min-width: 220px) and (max-width: 480px)
```

do you even add meta tag like that can you check it ?

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```